# How to delete dataset in Carto?

Tags: carto

I uploaded the incorrect file. How do I delete this dataset from my map or account?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click in the whitespace on the record you want to delete
2. A context menu appears, with a delete button

Here is what it looks like:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the dataset row in the list (not on the name or any other button) and a tool menu will appear. You'll see a Delete button there.